# Modifying folder without modifying timestamp

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, touch, file-attributes

I'd like to change folder contents without having *Date modified* change.

I sometimes do cleanup runs on old folders, trying to make space or clean up temp files and dead-ends, or adding relevant links or tags for findability. When I do this, I don't want to change the folder to *Date modified: today 2015*, because my folders are sorted by *Date modified*. A project from 2010 should remain timestamped with its last modified date from 2010, because I've only made meta-changes, not actual changes.

Currently I use [SK Timestamp](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/SKTimeStamp.html) or [Attribute Changer](http://www.petges.lu/home/). I right click each folder before I want to make changes to it, I keep the Properties window open, make my modifications, then hit Apply to overwrite the original timestamps.

I'd like to do it more automated, like set a ***Cleanup Mode*** on the root folder `D:\Workspace` and until I pop that state no timestamps ever get changed in the subdirectories `Project2010`, `Project2013`..., `Project2015`

Either that or at least be able to copy the timestamp between 2 files. Like in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/764721/365353) that mentions `@COPY /B %1+,, %1`, but not with current date.
Usage like: `touch D:\Temp\Project2010\Source.txt Destination.ext`

Comment: you're modifying the contents of a folder, therefore the folder's modified timestamp gets updated as well.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025187/rules-for-date-modified-of-folders-in-windows-explorer

Comment: You could change the system date and time to the date time you wish to keep, then make your changes, then `w32tm /resync` to set the time back to current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had commented above with a couple of suggestions -- one involving modifying the system's date / time, and another involving `robocopy`.  The system date / time one is a bit of trouble and requires Internet access, and the `robocopy /dcopy:t` switch didn't work at all in my tests.

But I found a better solution anyway.  Use a `for` loop to capture the folder's date time to a variable.  Then after you've made whatever changes you wish, use `powershell` to put the folder's date / time back the way it was.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "dir=path\to\directory"
for %%I in (%dir%) do set "datetime=%%~tI"

:: Do whatever deletions and other maintenance you want here.

:: Then after all changes have completed, reset the dir timestamp.
powershell -command "(Get-Item '%dir%').LastWriteTime=(Get-Date '%datetime%')"
```